# angular 2 PrimeNG + spring boot file upload error 400

Tags: angular, spring-boot, primeng

I am trying to upload a file with primeNG to a spring boot server-side application.. But I am getting error 400..

here is my code:
**app.html**

```
<p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" url="http://localhost:8080/upload" (onUpload)="onUpload($event)" >
        <template pTemplate type="content">
            <ul *ngIf="uploadedFiles.length">
                <li *ngFor="let file of uploadedFiles">{{file.name}} - {{file.size}} bytes</li>
            </ul>
        </template>        
    </p-fileUpload>
```

**app.ts**

```
msgs: Message[];
  uploadedFiles: any[] = [];

    onUpload(event) {
        for(let file of event.files) {
            this.uploadedFiles.push(file);
        }

        this.msgs = [];
        this.msgs.push({severity: 'info', summary: 'File Uploaded', detail: ''});
    }
```

**Spring boot Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload",
            method=RequestMethod.POST, 
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED) ResponseEntity processUpload(@RequestParam("myfile") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

            return ResponseEntity.ok("Fichier En cours de Traitement..");
    }
```

**CORS Config**

```
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) sRes;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) sReq;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, Cache-Control, Accept");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Authorization");

        if("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            fc.doFilter(sReq, response);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: What does the server say? I mean, does this 400 response have a body? Also, try using `name="myfile"`; I am using the same stack and "myfile[]" doesn't work for me.

Comment: That's the solution..!!! thanks @IlyaNovoseltsev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `name="myfile"` in your PrimeNG upload - this is the name your Spring controller expects.

**app.html**:

```
<p-fileUpload name="myfile" url="http://localhost:8080/upload" 
    (onUpload)="onUpload($event)" >
            <template pTemplate type="content">
                <ul *ngIf="uploadedFiles.length">
                    <li *ngFor="let file of uploadedFiles">{{file.name}} - {{file.size}} bytes</li>
                </ul>
            </template>        
        </p-fileUpload>
```